# Is it all right to ask to be accepted/upvoted? [poll]

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you’ve answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicate)

Is it all right to ask the question owner to upvote/accept your answer if the question owner comments that my answer helped solve his problems, but didn't vote or accept an answer?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicate

Comment: @gnovice and I thought I've searched enough before asking.. Maybe I should use google next time :-(

Comment: Do you feel dirty vs. is it ok:  they are a bit different.

Comment: They are both regarding the general acceptibility of this specific practice. While it is true that they are not verbatim duplicates, I feel that the intent of each is the same.

Comment: Even though I agree with you EB, I don't feel like we should be guessing the intent of the posters.  The questions are asking different things, even if the intent may be the same.

Comment: @mmyers, I call shenanigans!!  My spellchecker doesn't catch alright, thus it is a word!!!

Comment: I hate      polls.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

Go ahead if you see that the question owner says it helped.

Answer (score 3):

**Up to you**.

It's all right in that you aren't gonna get in trouble.
It is up to you whether or not you think it is ethical.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

It's not good manner.