# Is it wrong to ask for a correct answer to be chosen?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)
>   [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)

Would it be against etiquette to politely ask someone (perhaps a newer user)—or at least remind them that it's possible—to select a correct answer for a question?

Particularly when it's quite obvious an answer helped, and they used similar code in another related question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce) and [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat).