# What can I do if a user doesn't accept my answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)

On Stack Overflow I've answered a new user's homework question.

It is clear that I helped him and my answer is the only one, however, (assuming that because he is new) he didn't accept my answer.

I know I shouldn't be "farming" the board for points but it's a bit annoying to see my efforts go "unrewarded". I was wondering what is the course of action here. Do I wait for him to notice?

Comment: You mean unrewarded by the asker. You still get rep from upvotes and bounties awarded by others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't do anything right now. You should wait for the user to respond to you, e.g. if he needs more clarification or doesn't know how to solve his problem with your answer.

Regardless, there's no obligation for people to accept answers. Posting comments like, "Please accept my answer" are noise and – when it comes down to it – quite rude. You can ask the OP if he needs more help or if something was unclear with your answer, offering to improve it and add information.

Eventually, a "0% accept rate" shown for this OP will get him the usual "y u no accept answers?" comments from the community, so sooner or later they'll probably follow up on their questions and accept answers.

But even then, if it doesn't happen, don't worry. Two upvotes weigh more than the score you get from an accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

This is normal - nothing "blatant" about it.

Some users do not accept answers - you need to learn to live with it.

<sup>I have gotten answer accepted a couple of years later... don't lose hope ;)</sup>

Comment: I like the small font for the last line :)

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that:

- **New users** quickly learn that not selecting an answer effects them, and before long if they are using Stack Exchange often, they'll come back to select an answer.  Meaning that if you're answering questions for new users, expect that you might not get selected as an answer right away. Further, if the user never plans to use Stack Exchange again, don't expect to them to learn how to select an answer, or that you'll later get selected as an answer.
- **Experienced users** know that it's in their best interest to select an answer if one is in fact provided. Meaning if you're answering questions from an experienced user that has a low acceptance rate for selecting an answer, don't be surprised if the user doesn't select your answer as the answer.

Either way, don't ping the user with comments requesting they select your answer as the answer.