# Is it polite/legal to ask the question owner to mark my answer as the best?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

Is it polite/legal to ask the question owner: "mark my answer as the best"?

The reason asking is that I've been asked that, and not sure how to respond. Obviously I would only upvote or mark that answer as accepted if I find it worth it. However, do such claims deserve a flag?

Comment: I sometimes remind a question owner to accept *some* answer. I try not to explicitly ask them to accept *my* answer, though I suppose that's implied. (This doesn't answer your question; I'm not saying that being more direct is or is not polite.) Oh, and don't forget to accept an answer. 8-)}

Comment: Related: [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773)

Comment: Absolutely impolite.  The whole idea behind SO is that you post content for the good of the site, not because you want some silly, meaningless counter (whose value is so prominently displayed and compared to others') incremented.

Comment: No, don't do it.  And don't ask users to accept an answer (in generalm it's a form of asking them to improve accept rate).  The system nags them.  Comments about accepting answers at all are redundant noise (since the system reminds them).  We'd prefer that you not say anything at all.

Answer (score 8):

It's about as impolite as hotel bellhop that pauses at your door for a tip after he brings up your luggage.  You're not obligated to give him/her one, and perhaps he/she is being a bit pushy, but it should be treated as a prompt and nothing further.

I don't think the practice of reminding the OP of one's answer should be actively encouraged, but if the asker has been away from their question for a time and a new answer was posted, the answerer may just be poking to make sure the OP is still around (perhaps ignorant of the fact that new answers alert the inbox).

Definitely not a flaggable offense unless it turns into blatant harassment and/or rude behavior.

Comment: It is even less impolite, since the bellhop is getting paid anyway, and in real currency too.

Comment: @Asad Yes, but the accepted answer can be thought of as a rep "tip" for providing the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I just meant to highlight the fact that answerers on SO are volunteers.

Answer (score 5):

A polite request for a green check does not deserve a flag and does not demand a response, let alone a green check.

An impolite request might deserve a flag.

Answer (score 1):

Asking a user to accept your answer isn't necessarily impolite to them, as long as you're not obnoxious about it.

However, if there are competing answers, clamoring for the OP's attention *is* sort of unfair to the other answerers. Let the answers stand on their own merits. If you feel the need to politely remind the OP to accept an answer, it would be nice to do it as a comment on the question without singling out your own answer, in order to give everyone else a fair chance.