# What happens if a question asker never marks or hints that an answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

What would happen? They would have no indication of it being what worked for them, unlike [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692).

Comment: You would never know if the answer worked.  That's what would happen.

Comment: If the OP does nothing, then (tautologically) nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would happen?

**It just waits there waiting for its owner to return.**

It keeps getting bounced up the feed by the community user, at regular intervals for any more helpful answers. [Post regarding the details regarding question bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/302377)

The problem with such questions is that; even though there are multiple answers underneath it, we can never know whether it helped the OP or not.

From personal experience, commenting underneath the question like this helps:

> Did one of the answers here help you? If yes, then maybe you'd want to accept one of them.

Comment: Not having an accepted answer is only _a part_ of the formula for determining if a question is eligible for Community user bumping. Additionally, the question itself must be nonnegatively-scored, and have no positively-scored answers. ([Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511)) So not all questions without an accepted answer are bumped up the feed by Community.

Comment: @arjafi Thank You. Added the details in the answer :)