# Disable showing post title instead of URL when linked in a post or comment in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, auto-linking

Whenever you type a link, like this one: [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692), it comes up as the title of the question linked. Is there a way to disable this functionality for me only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable that, and I think that is okay (It is the default behavior on the site and in the apps). Why not show this useful information? If you really want the link, just tap and hold. You can copy the URL then.

You can workaround that though. You can do that by wrapping it, in a code block for example, but that would change it for everyone:

```
[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692)
```

Result:

[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109773/318692)