# Is it rude to ask for some answer to be accepted?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking for someone to accept your Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

If a question has one or more answers, and the OP is clearly satisfied with one or more of them, but none was accepted, is it rude to leave a comment  asking for one of them to be accepted?

In my opinion, saying something like "accept my answer!" is not appropriate, but politely asking for *some* answer to be accepted is ok, even if one of the answers is mine. Am I right, or is that rude?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No it isn't rude (depending on how you go about it). New users need to be pointed in the right direction when it comes to asking and answering. I don't think it hurts to politely ask a user to accept (your) answer, especially if said user has posted a "thank you" comment.

Usually I leave something like:

> Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.

I don't think that's too annoying, and, in the case of a new user, it educates them on how the site operates.

Answer (score 9):

There's a reason for the accept rate, the coloring, meta, the FAQ, etc.  I won't say it's *rude* per se, but there's a lot of noise around this area in the form of comments which doesn't really *need* to exist.

If you *must* leave a comment, and if the user doesn't accept *any* answer after a reasonable amount of time, at least go back and delete the comment.  People who's exposure to the site for the first time through that page won't get the best impression about our users if all they see is badgering for something that's *completely optional*.

And of course if they *do* accept an answer, go back and delete the comment, as it's now obsolete and it shouldn't be the responsibility of others to clean up after you (just because they can doesn't mean they should have to).

Comment: I agree that the comment should be removed once an answer has been accepted as it now serves no purpose. Regarding the amount of noise surrounding this issue, I agree it's larger than it should be, but IMO accepting an answer makes the site better since it makes it easier and quicker for people to find the right solution/explanation etc. (which is why it's encouraged through reputation), so asking for an answer to be accepted makes the site better eventually.

Comment: @spatz Yes, it might, but two things: a) accepting an answer is completely voluntary on the part of the user, a user is perfectly welcome to *not* participate in the gaming aspects of the site and should not be pressured in an inappropriate way because others choose to engage in the game. b) the accepted answer is what the *asker* decides is what's best for that person, while others have indicated that the two *often* coincide, that's not always the case and when it isn't, it's not what's best for the site.