# Is it OK to ask for acceptance?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Sometimes on Stackoverflow, you give a good answer, many upvotes, but the asker does not accept your answer. Is it OK to explicitly ask to accept the answer?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: It depends. If the OP has never accepted an answer, then it's fine to push him/her in the right direction. Personally, I stopped caring about accepts a long time ago. The +15 is just a small bonus. Though I admit that there was a recent case where I wanted the accept badly because the answer had enough votes to appear on my profile. (and two badges as well)

Comment: I don't care for the points, or for accept rate. However, if a question does have a correct answer, it's better if it has a tick mark, for future visitors. So if the OP indicates that an answer is good, a gentle reminder to accept it won't harm.