# Many users don't accept answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

On the StackExchange sites I answer quite a few questions, but I find that once the answer (or even a few answers) is there then the user just leaves the question never to see it again. They also do this before even accepting or upvoting an answer.

Could something be done to remind users to accept an answer which will then close the question? Then it won't appear as unanswered and the answerer will receive his/her reputation points.

Comment: make the user enter their phone number when posting an answer so SO can make automated calls to them to accept an answer

Comment: It will always be the user's last unalienable right, and you shall not tread on his/her right to accept...  Point-wise, it's usually a negligible issue.

Comment: @SamIam Jeff already makes housecalls with a giant S. Perhaps we can fit these reminders into his schedule as well.

Comment: @Adel Negligible for high rep users, you mean.

Comment: I know what you mean, I was not talking only about rep, but also them still being listed as unanswered, yet I fully understand the problems involved.

Comment: @AndrewC - that's true. Well, I guess users just need to  nag one another to accept(although that doesn't sit well with many of us)

Comment: No, @Adel, users should _not_ nag each other to accept. There used to be mechanisms to encourage people to accept, but in the end, it was all rather unwelcoming. Other users are here for knowledge sharing and learning, not for rep scraping. Acceptance is about whether you're satisfied with the answer - if you feel you'd like more you shouldn't be put under pressure by rep-hungry answerers to accept.

Comment: @AndrewC - agreed, That's a very good point. thanks!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. How do you know they never see it again?
2. SO has moved away, strongly, from nagging users about accepting answers, for a variety of reasons.

Bottom line, such is life, and it's unlikely to change.

Comment: @ehope5, This post should be marked as THE answer to you question.....

Comment: I would fin it VERY ironic if this question never received an accepted answer...

Comment: Haha, maybe I should have done that? .....

Comment: @ohope5 *I* woulda laughed.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with 15 rep can upvote an answer. Questions with an upvoted answer are not considered "unanswered".

I consider an accepted answer to be a "super upvote", but not something I'm entitled to. If you're worried about users who never accept an answer in your life, you could avoid answering questions from users with very low rep.

Comment: People with high reputation don't ask much questions.

Comment: @Michel: Where do you get that idea? We have plenty of people with high reputation numbers that have done little _except_ ask questions.

Comment: ok,sorry.
I meant to say that generally,questions are usually asked more by people with less reputation, specially 1st time users

Answer (score 1):

SO is giving +2 for accepting answers to encourage the same.