# Could we get the 'Community' user to prompt new users to accept an answer if they've commented 'Thanks'?

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users, community-user

Just a thought, a lot of the time I stumble across questions where an answer has a comment from the Question OP, along the lines of:

> Thanks <Answerer>! This helped a bunch!

And I find myself writing a comment on the answer to the tune of:

> Hi @NewUser1234 - Glad to see that we were able to solve your problem! If this answer helped you, you could mark it as your 'accepted answer' by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. This will award *<Answerer>* (and yourself!) with some bonus rep points, and help future visitors to your question know which answer worked for you :)

Sometimes the user accepts, sometimes they don't, but at least they know they can.

I was wondering if this process could be automated? Perhaps the Community User Bot could keep an eye out for a 'Thanks' comment from the OP, and just leave a comment to remind them that they **can** accept if they wish?

For example, the parameters could be:

- The question/answer is over 2 days old.
- The answer is >= 1 total score.
- The Question OP has < 100 rep.
- There is a comment from the question OP containing *'Thanks'* or *'Thank you'*.
- There **isn't** a comment that contains *'accept'* or *'accepted'*

What do you think?

---

Edit: This is a request for a *different* feature to the [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer). that suggestion talks about having a popup when the OP **posts** a 'thanks' comment. The effects of this are immediate and also a little intimidating.

This feature request on the other hand, wants a comment to be added **days later.** This takes away any pressure to 'accept', and acts more as an "FYI, you **can** accept", not an explicit order to do so.

Comment: Forget the comment about `accepted`, and just limit to not commenting if there is no accepted answer. I disagree with the score of the answer, often the OP won't be able to vote up, even if it works. 1 day not 2 and maybe <=50 rep.

Comment: @Tim - The 'accept' part is there because if someone else has already told them how to accept an answer we don't want another comment along the same lines. I chose 2 days to give ample time for other answers, and the fact that this is also the period of time you have to wait to start a bounty, it seemed to fit better. I put a score there because that usually means at least one other person agreed with the answer, not necessarily the OP.

Comment: But accept is based on the OP's opinion, not another users.

Comment: Yeah, of course it is :), I'm not saying that the community should accept it, just that if a) the OP has said 'thanks' and b) The answer is fairly well received, then we should remind the OP that they can accept if they wish.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea of Community User leaving comments.
She should stay doing background processing and fixing obvious issues around the site, etc.

Also, it's not a rule that users have to upvote answers or even accept, so it could only be a gently reminder, and a comment might be a bit much, and create much clutter everywhere.
A popup message would be better.

I like your idea in principle, to remind users when they've not accepted can only be a good thing - but only if it would work.

### Caveats

> The answer is >= 1 total score.

Why does it need an upvote to be worthy of being accepted?

> The Question OP has < 100 rep.

Having more than 100 rep does not negate forgetfulness, or a bad OP who never accepts answers.

> There is a comment from the question OP containing 'Thanks' or 'Thank
>   you'.

Too much potential for false positives.

What if the comment is "Thanks/thank you for your attempt, but your code doesn't work can you fix it please"?

Or "No Thanks, this does not answer my question at all".

etc

> There isn't a comment that contains 'accept' or 'accepted'

More potential for false positives. Such as if someone commented "I accept this answer works ok, but using X with Y is not ideal".
Or "It's accepted that `mysql_query` is depreciated but I have to use it"

Also, this is a *great deal* of checking so many things just to remind OP to accept an answer.
Not sure this approach is worthwhile.

Comment: a [popup message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer) has been rejected as being too forceful, Users shouldn't be under any pressure to accept (as you mention). As for answers to the caveats you list: 1) It doesn't need to be *upvoted* to be accepted, but generally if an answer has an upvote then it helped someone. We could potentially lower this prereq to 0 score if need be - (remember this is just for adding a comment only, hell the score could be -16 and it'd still be valid for acceptance). (cont.)

Comment: 2) No, but this comment isn't about forgetfulness of regular users, but about **new users**. Someone with 100+ rep can generally be considered as knowing the basics of how SE works, that's when most of the privileges start to kick in. This comment is just supposed to be an FYI for the New Users 3) Do you know of any statistics on how many comments are 'thanks that worked' vs 'thanks but blah'? Of course, there *is* a potential for false positives, but I think it'd be in the 10% or less for this situation.

Comment: 4) This one I'm sure will have even *less* potential for false positives, the example you cite is worded really weirdly, and I can't think of many other situations where 'accept' would be used. (Note that I left off 'acceptable' for this reason)

Comment: (1) "*hell the score could be -16 and it'd still be valid for acceptance*" So why your limit of `>1`? You argue against yourself there really. (2) "*Someone with 100+ rep can generally be considered as knowing the basics of how SE works*" Absolutely incorrect. Rep does not ever indicate knowledge of the site. I would argue this even if you stated "1000 rep means site knowledge". Sure, "usually" but "usually" is no way to base a site function on! Factually and accurately are key here!

Comment: (3) "*Do you know of any statistics on how many comments are 'thanks that worked' vs 'thanks but blah'?*" I'm sure I could find enough *manually* to make your idea non-viable. "*I think it'd be in the 10% or less for this situation*" You ask me for stats, but then make a presumption based on no facts or stats at all? Ok, I think there are 90%, so now it;s up to you to prove otherwise, it's your feature request ;)

Comment: (4) "*This one I'm sure will have even less potential for false positives*" You're sure based on what? Do you have statistics? - "*I can't think of many other situations where 'accept' would be used*" Think is something we do when we recall memories. That essentially translates to you have not seen many instances of this. Which in no way tells us if it's a potential problem or not. Of course I have no statistics for these things, but common sense and experience of the sites shows these "common words" are used in scenarios outside your wanting to use them to ID a specific comment.

Comment: Additionally, of the "false positive" examples I gave, they are actually from memory, having seen such comments and not too rare either. Of course people will use the word "thank" in many ways other than actually thanking them for the "useful answer which should be accepted". The same with "accept". It's not limited to just my examples above, there are hundreds of usages of these words which would create false positives. "I won't `accept` this answer because XYZ" and so on...

Comment: Again, I like your idea of prompting people to accept answers. This is a good thing for the site, I just don't think your specific approach and limitations are valid. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777 - and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177304/230506