# Thank you comments suggestion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Recently a lot of suggestions were added for different situations on the site. For instance if I write a question and add words like 'problem' I get an error saying I should not use this word in a question title.

Still from time to time it happens to me that I have an answer with zero upvotes and that is not accepted but it gets a comment like `Thanks a ton you saved my day!` or `I can not express my gratitude`. I could leave a comment like `you may as well consider upvoting/accepting the answer`, but I feel somewhat awkward to write such comments.

I would like to suggest that whenever a user writes `thank you` or something of a sort in a comment, a suggestion comes out that he/she should maybe upvote the answer/comment he/she is thankful about. This of course should not be an error because it will not be appropriate every time but still a mild suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Comments that just say a version of 'Thanks' shouldn't be getting left in the first place. See the comment tooltip that says: *""Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”"*

Comment: I know. My point is that there should also be a suggestion about what should the user do instead

Comment: Actually, a "you saved my day" should translate into an Accept. An upvote means "this was useful information".

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree. Still I have some comments of this sort that are not from the author of the question and then the user can not accept my answer.

Comment: But then somebody's going to come along and say "no, accepting answers should be *completely optional* and in no way are we to impose on users to accept answers", whilst completely missing the point about users saying thanks when they really meant to be accepting answers instead because that's *how* we thank answerers on SO.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a [meta-tag:feature-request]? I'm sure I suggested something very similar not too long ago, but I can't find it now - my thoughts were - if the user hasn't accepted any answers yet (or maybe not in a while (maybe with the user below a certain reputation), in case the user forgot), every time a comment matches some pattern (e.g. containing "thank" or "solved") display a popup pointing the user to a resource on how to accept answers.

Comment: @Dukeling it is a feature request thanks

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn that's why i say it should be optional

Comment: Please check first if I already voted. It would suck to see this message even if you already voted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nudge for low rep users that leave 'thank you' comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157753/nudge-for-low-rep-users-that-leave-thank-you-comments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking users to accept answer when they comment that it answers their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88535/282094