# Posting a late, very detailed, answer

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

I know it's a bit whiny post a comment about it, but I've spent the last 1½ hours writing an alternative solution and proving that it is far better performance-wise.

Now, over more than an hour has passed and it hasn't received a single upvote (yet the other answers have received plenty).

Was it just because I was too late with the answer, so the attention on [the (still unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295711/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position/12297231#12297231) has faded?

Secondly, what do you guys have of tips to post a late, but detailed answer?

To me, it seemed like a question other people could be asking in the future as well, so I figured it was worth it, even though the OP probably just wanted a quick solution.

But since I don't really get any rep out of it, it seems that it isn't really worth the hassle. Shouldn't it be?

**UPDATE**:

Not only is this question resolved, I also got upvoted on the post I wined about, so the sole reason I'm keeping this question here is so other people (including myself) can see it in the future.

Comment: Just move on. There's no obligation on *anyone* to vote for your answer.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, and I will, don't worry, the focus is more on the second part of my question.

Comment: If rep is your primary motive, it might indeed not be worth the hassle. But I'm sure that over time it will pick up some. And you've made the internet a better place. That's worth far more to me than some upvotes.

Comment: @Bart You're right, now that you say it that way, that's the whole reason I started making the answer in the first place. I guess I'm primarily whining because I feel my rep is too low compared to my desire to contribute. Nevermind all this.

Comment: You're here for 4 months now. Just keep contributing and the rep will come. I've said it before, but SO to me is worth far more based on what I've learned (and hope to have taught) than the rep I've earned. Some of the privileges are nice, but that's about it. I'm far more active on SO as an editor than I am as an answerer and still I have over 6K at the moment. The rep will come automatically. Just focus on what's important.

Comment: @Bart I agree, but more than that, shouldn't it be more encouraged to do this - from SO's side? I'm sure this has been discussed many times before.

Comment: Should what be more encouraged?

Comment: @Bart To provide more detailed answers, instead of all the quickies that will give you rep more now:
[6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: Nevermind, I think that discussion is too big for this question.

Comment: You might want search for FGITW or "Fastest Gun in the West" here on Meta for some views on that. My view is "screw what everybody else does. Just take your time. No matter if the others gain more rep in doing what they do". But then again, it often seems I have a different approach to this whole thing than a lot of other users.

Comment: @Bart While I agree with your most of your view, I still think reputation should ultimately reflect how good users are at contributing to the site (I know it does for the top 100 rep people, since they wouldn't be rising that fast if it weren't for solid answers giving them constant rep). I guess I just had to write this question to realize that my focus isn't on rep.

Comment: Also, your time is better invested on a few popular tags that simply receive more attention, this is regardless of the answer quality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are here for the rep,  just take the easy questions and hope to be first.

But if you are here to help, just go ahead and be patient.  Sooner or later, people will recognize your effort. I have had some answers that received 30+ upvotes over a period of 3+ years. And they are still collecting. While the easy ones get a few upvotes right away, and never get any attention after that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I realized this quickly after posting. I'll accept your answer whenever the time limit is out.

Comment: [One of my **very** late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) was rewarded with a Populist badge B)