# Is it okay to use another user's comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Let's give some context. I've read some comments of the user [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) that I find pretty complete and useful (on StackOverflow), so I was wondering if I could use those comments too, in other words, post the same comment. The comments in question are:

> Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

and this one:

> It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

**Related:** [Is posting someone's comment as an answer okay?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157889/is-posting-someones-comment-as-an-answer-okay) (The difference is that I want to use those comments as comments, not in an answer)

Comment: Use them... how? You want to copy them to comment elsewhere?

Comment: I wonder if I could post the same comment. Is there any problem with it? Because it seems like the user who wrote it put effort.

Comment: Heh. I guess normal attribution requirements come into play here. You need to at least say who originally came up with that content... Unless Martijn gives his blessing.

Comment: Check if they are not already present in [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136609/185667)

Comment: Didn't know about [AutoReviewComments script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). I will install it! But those comments are not there anyway.

Comment: Those comments are too verbose for my liking, try "Debug your own crap" and "Build me a yacht and I'll write your code" <-- you have my permission to use those.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments are [Subscriber Content](https://stackexchange.com/legal), the same standards apply to them as do to questions and answers as per the Terms of Service.

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

Also, if you look at the site footer, you will see:

> [image]

So, strictly, when you copy and use a comment, you will need to link back to the original and attribute to the author.

Pragmatically, no one would be displeased if you happen to reuse a comment related to content feedback, as it's for the benefit of the community.

Comment: I know this is opinion-based, but how should I act? Strictly or pragmatically? What would you recommend?

Comment: @Christian If you feel a comment is *worth the extra effort* of adding a link back and mentioning the author's name, go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use it.

If original comment is long, then

- don't forget about authorship ("As @MartijnPieters stated"). Make sure to link to the comment author's profile page in case there (a) are multiple users with the same display name or (b) the user ever changes their display name
- don't comment on the same post, where you copied comment from

If original comment is short or typical, I don't think you run into something unexpected after reposting it.

Comment: So, how can I put the *authorship*? Something like *"The comment here. By @MartijnPieters"*?

Comment: Maybe "As @MartijnPieters stated"?