# Comments asking for upvotes/accepts

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I happened upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818084/sleep-function-in-c) question, where the questioner commented on every answer with `"I'd love an up vote!"`

Is it correct to flag such clutter, perhaps as `not constructive / off-topic`, or is there a better way to correct users that beg for up votes (and similar behavior) via comments.

Comment: That lady was doing it on all of her questions. Just burned about 25 comment flags from this lady begging for votes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That kind of comment is basically noise, so either "not constructive" or "too chatty" would work.  A custom flag of "asking for upvotes" is fine too.

Comment: Thanks!  And in the time it took for this answer to become eligible to be accepted, all of those comments were cleaned up.