# Is it ever appropriate to ask new users to mark your answer as correct or ask for an upvote?

Tags: discussion, comments

This question is related to meta: [Begging for Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)

I received [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862199/how-to-manage-what-to-display-in-a-gridview-from-a-dropdown-list/19862303#comment29550309_19862303) telling me not to "beg" for upvotes/mark as correct.

I posted the "offending" comment because the OP was asking his first question, and because he left a comment thanking me for my help and telling me he had found the solution thanks to me.  Generally in that case I remind the user to please mark my answer as correct and/or upvote if they found it helpful.

I do NOT ask for upvotes/accepts unless the user is new and leaves a "thanks" comment instead of upvote/accept.

I don't consider this begging, I consider this reminding new users not to leave answered questions marked as unanswered, and to use the feedback system.  I can see where mentioning an upvote might be considered a different matter than accepts.

Was I in the wrong?  If so, what line did I cross?

**Edit:**

As one of the commenters pointed out, I do feel the question linked below directly addresses the topic I wanted to bring up.  I'll avoid mentioning upvotes in the future.  Thanks.

[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)

Comment: Read through some of the questions in the "related" tab.  There are *lots* of questions on the topic.

Comment: In all fairness if they've explicitly said your answer (and only your answer) helped them then it seems fair enough.  I might have phased it as accepting **an** answer however (which would inevitably end up being yours)

Comment: Thanks, I did read through suggested questions before posting but somehow the "related questions" seem to be more on topic.  Even so, this is in reference specifically to a single question where the user indicated that they felt my answer was the best one, not a user who habitually fails to accept/upvote.

Comment: I wouldn't have mentioned upvoting however,  not least because a user at 1 rep **can't** upvote

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks for the feedback, I will keep those things in mind.

Comment: While i have to admit the wording "begging" might have been a little harsh, as well as not being correct. I should've used "asking" in this case. I don't see anything wrong in encouraging users to accept answers, it was the phrasing of your comment, which made me post that comment. "... *please upvote* and/ **or** mark the answer as correct." Where the *or* emphasizes upvote part even more. In addition the OP (being new) doesn't gain anything from that. And i don't think a short explanation why he should consider accepting an answer would have taken that more time and would leave less noise.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Thanks for your feedback, I will be more careful in this area in the future.

Comment: @pseudocoder :) You're welcome. It's not about being careful, but rather about that you can be constructive by helping new users with a simple effort of rephrasing a comment :) (*btw* [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841167/jibx-error-in-the-jibx-code/19841722#comment29550257_19841722) is much worse)

Comment: @pseudocoder Btw Thanks, for your comments too, i should consider rephrasing my comments, too. As "begging" may sound insulting to users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggesting a new user accepts **an** answer is reasonable enough if they state that as a result of the answers their problem is solved. I would avoid suggesting it be your answer however (although it is likely to end up that way)

I wouldn't have mentioned upvoting however, not least because a user at 1 rep **can't** upvote

Comment: The guy who was correcting me also suggested linking http://stackoverflow.com/about to new users who fail to accept.  I thought that was a good idea.