# Upvotes as centralized currency

Tags: discussion

I remember reading a blog post a long time ago (forget link) that claimed that centralized currencies allowed positive feedback in that the rich got richer while the poor always had to scramble by.

Centralized currencies allowed the rise of aristocrats to become wealthy even though they did not provide value (e.g. create shoes, fight in battle, build houses, etc...) The previous barter economy of course had problems of itself.

My economic background is too weak to grasp this strongly but I think there is an interesting point here. I was just reading a post on how a new user was frustrated at getting enough votes to start using SOs features.

Perhaps a new model of "currency" would be interesting. (Not necessarily for SO, just as a general idea) Maybe each user would start with a certain amount of "units of whatever"(UOWs -> WOWS) and people could exchange WOWs (like the current bounty system except as a core feature rather than an added feature) for answers. When an account becomes "bankrupt" all its posts could be deleted (or ranked down, or have the default text color be white, etc...) Questions would also require "upkeep" in that each question would drain slowly and eventually disappear unless people donated to its "repair". Really good questions could be placed on "historical significance" list with no upkeep cost and the top 7 would be know as the "7 Wondrous Questions of Eternity"

Just some random thoughts :)

EDIT: Yeesh! so much negativity on an idea that isn't necessarily for SO

EDIT2: Think of how an economist would see votes. Votes are valued. Votes equal prestige. Votes can only be transferred in unit sums from person to person and only once. Votes do not require sacrifice to give. How liquid is this economy? How easily do the richest amass their wealth and what percentage of all the wealth do they own? I think this is a very interesting question...I am not saying we should change SO I'm just wondering why every forum is copying Reddit's(or whoever) upvote thingy without understanding the human dynamics it creates.

Comment: Very random, yes. ;)

Comment: What exactly is the point of this complex currency system? As in, how would this improve the site in any way?

Comment: Seems to be turning SE into more of a game, rather than a Q&A network. (Spoiler: Jon Skeet wins)

Comment: Well the thing is the current method is already a currency system. I'm just examining it's pros and cons and comparing to other currency systems.

Comment: If you think that nobody here has even considered the effects that the existence of voting has on this community then you clearly have not done your research.  It has been discussed *quite a lot* here on meta, how votes affect the site, how various site features affect votes, and so on.  If you think that it was just tacked onto the site as an afterthought without consideration, you are mistaken.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a game.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for an economist's outlook on this. Thank you for enlightening me @Servy, Your friendly comments are always appreciated. I guess the point that centralized currencies by THEIR NATURE encourage wealth to amass into single points is not worth discussing as it's already been discussed before.

Comment: @Doorknob Some pepole believe Wallstreet treats the economy as a game for them to take advantage off. Anything can be viewed as a game if you abstract it enough. Economics is the game of "maximizing efficiency" for example. If you're saying "it's not serious enough" I disagree. A currency system is very serious and implemented properly can be used to, in this case, maximize knowledge or efficiency of spreading knowledge.

Comment: I don't know that I'd compare reputation to a currency system. You can't really buy anything with your unicorn points (short of exposure with bounties), nor trade them with others. They have no effective value at all, and once you clear the 20k threshold to unlock the last set of moderation tools, there is no difference at all between a 100k and 20k user. There's no real concept of someone being "richer" in this system. Also, inflation would be rampant, as reputation generally only increases for every user.

Comment: Considering rep as directly equivilant to currency is a flaud premise; when I upvote you (which I certainly haven't on this one) you gain rep but it doesn't come from me

Comment: @RichardTingle You don't think it would be interesting to discuss why it's a flawed premise? Or even listen to people who disagree?

Comment: @user2483724 Pardon? I think we may have misunderstood each other somewhere

Comment: @user2483724 You haven't really brought up any particularly interesting ideas to discuss.  Saying, "Voting is interesting, now go off and discuss that since I don't understand it" isn't really contributing to the community.  When you have something particularly meaningful to discuss, something that is both original and has meaningful implications, *then* there's reason to discuss it.

Comment: @BradLarson but [I want a sandwich if I ever visit...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191306/meaningless-points-ive-an-idea-meaningful-points) (and adding that set of posts into the links here)

Comment: I am a relative late-comer to Stack Overflow. Sure, my account is nearly 5 years old, but I didn't become active until July 2012 (see my [network reputation graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation)). I have had **no problems** gaining reputation; I am now listed in the overall top 40. Noone is trying to keep me poor and downtrodden. There is no proletariat here.

Comment: Oh we tried @MartijnPieters. We tried and failed ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are incorrect. I am trying to keep you poor and downtrodden. I'm just not terribly effective, what with my activity being so prominent ;)

Comment: [Reputation isn't currency](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204719/is-reputation-the-currency-of-stack-overflow) in any way shape or form. Of course you could argue "getting reputation is difficult because there are so many users better than I am", but we also have an insane amount of questions coming in every day, making obtaining reputation really not impossible.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I am sure that as soon as you learn Python I'll feel the crushing heel of your boot!

Comment: downvotes on meta are different. downvotes on meta are just love.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Python Boots](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/f/frank+zappa/stinkfoot_20056989.html)

Comment: If we were given starbucks gift cards for 10000 rep , ... I might tolerate this shadiness

Comment: @HansUp: Thanks, the image of Andrew Barber with stinkfoot due to too tight Python boots is now forever embedded in my mind..

Comment: After about a year, I'm reaching the conclusion this would've made a real [tag:fun] thingie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Votes are not intended to be currency.  You can't just buy prestige, you need to **earn** it.  Many upvotes mean (on Meta) that people agree with your point of view.  Over on SO it means people find your answer useful.  **That** is what gives you prestige; the ability to be a valuable asset.  If you just bought your way to the top, what value is that to anyone but yourself?

After further digesting your post, another major flaw is the premise of the site.  SO isn't here to be kept for a limited amount fo time, it's meant to be a repository.  An everlasting (in online terms) repository of the best answers.  Making that "go away" without being constantly purchased with WOWs goes against the concept of the site.

Comment: Actually, the issue of making things "go away" came to mind because the method of doing things for a framework of a different version can be different, yet the question is asked the same. SO askers rarely also say "How to blah-blah-blah with Thing version 2.3.0". Isn't that an issue? But that's besides the point...it was just an example and meant as more of a joke to illustrate potential applications. A real implementation of degrading old-questions with out-dated answers would require more finesse.