# What does the up arrow in the "top posts" section of the user profile mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, top-questions, top-answers

When I'm looking some user profiles via ios-app, I noticed that most of the time all visible user's "top posts" are marked with an up arrow sign. But sometimes, I see posts without this sign. Here they are (top posts from top users):

> [image: Bill]

- [Link to the selected post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/339911)

---

> [image: animuson]

- [Link to the selected post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250922/339911)

---

> [image: Robert]

- [Link to the selected post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884/339911)

---

What does this arrow mean and why is it not showed on certain posts?

Comment: No idea, but they *all* have an up arrow (albeit a different arrow) on iPhone...

Comment: @Cai I think iPad is cursed.

Comment: On my iPhone, it shows as an upwards triangle (the same symbol used for the 'upvote comment' link in the iOS app)

Comment: I believe the arrow means "this is the score of the post" and as far as know, should always be there. The fact it's missing from some posts for you is probably some weird bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.6.

The lack of arrow just meant that the title was really long and the system chose to collapse arrow before ellipsising the text.  Now the arrow won't collapse.