# Too small width of the user list

Tags: bug, ios-app

After app crashed when I'm editing the post, I seen user list with too small width:

> [image: width]

I can scroll, select any user profile, but width of the list stays too small. After switching to another SE site, problem is gone.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this?  I've seen a few times times but am struggling to make it happen consistently.

Comment: @BrianNickel probably, not. But I got this bug when collecting info for [another one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287686/339911). Hope this help.