# Broken icon in the Top posts section of the profile page in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[User's profile page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190461/timurvi) contains probably a part of some strange icon in the Top posts section:

> [image: top posts]

This bug appears only if you open profile page from any post. When opened from users tab, profile looks differently (as in [related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287686/339911)):

> [image: user list]

Possible reason is a width of Top posts block on the screen.

Suspicious post has been migrated to meta site.

- App Version: 1.6.3.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.6.

For some reason, the button and the text had the same horizontal compression resistance, and the text won out.

Comment: Will related bug be fixed too?